# UI-grid - define type by cell

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a editable UI-grid in my page. The first column is a dropdownlist with many options. Depending on the item that the user selects in this first column, the second column must accept only number or hexadecimal.

It's possible to define type from a specific cell? Does anybody have a example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

type

the type of the column, used in sorting. If not provided then the grid will guess the type. Add this only if the grid guessing is not to your satisfaction. One of:

'string',
'boolean',
'number',
'date',
'object',
'numberStr' 
Note that if you choose date, your dates should be in a javascript date type

from http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
   columnDefs: [ { field: 'col1', name: 'First Column', type: 'number'} ],
   data: data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My idea of ​​setting the type is to prevent the user put characters when the item chosen in the dropdownlist before only accepts numbers ...

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueBiazinEsteves , I have 5 rows and I want to define different datatypes for each row, do you have any idea how to do it UI-Grid?